# tentativas de login no servidor de e-mail com usuários inexistentes

Tags: centos, postfix

Recentemente reparei em varias tentativas de login no servidor de e-mail com usuários inexistentes, olhando o log do postfix exitem varias linhas similares a está:

```
Nov  5 13:03:04 servename imapd: LOGIN FAILED, user=usuarioinexistente@umdominiohospedadonoservidor.com.br, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
```

Queria saber como debugar isso para encontrar a possível causa e resolver o problema, qualquer informação é util.

Comment: Esta pergunta está fora do [escopo do site](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Oi José, não há como debugar isso. Isso vai continuar a acontecer. Infelizmente isso é o dia a dia de um servidor e de quem mantém o servidor. Por isso é importante ter firewall, portas fechadas e updates em dia.

Comment: Você deve ter um sistema de bloqueio de brute force como o CSF ou fail2ban